# Постоянный алерт "Environment: Sandbox"

Tags: ios, iphone, apple

Приветствую.
При тестирования одного из приложений из TestFlight (естественно, не собственного) была попытка внутренней покупки, которая затем повела за собой бесконечные окошки "Environment: Sandbox"

[image: Скриншот]

Пытался удалять и скачивать заново приложение (уже не из Test); менять аккаунты iTunes, однако ничего не помогает.

**Как избавиться от надоедливого алерта?**

Comment: А как звучит ваш вопрос?

Comment: @0xdb Да, не учёл. Методы избавления от данной ошибки.